# Can Hotspot be configured to preserve its statistics between runs?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

The HotSpot compiler learns about your code as your process runs. Is there any way to configure it to persist what it's learned, so that the next time the process starts (assuming no jars or class files have changed), it doesn't need to start from scratch?

Comment: See  here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779339/java-jvm-hotspot-is-there-a-way-to-save-jit-performance-gains-at-compile-time

Comment: What does this have to do with Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There are other JVMs which can do this, though. Oracle JRockit, for example, allows you to save profiling information and compiled code. Excelsior JET also does this.

Comment: JRockit does not do this. We had a prototype of this many years ago, but the feature was eventually dropped for lack of resources and not providing enough benefit.

Comment: Excelsior JET goes one step further: it enables the developer to precompile the entire app, possibly together with the standard library classes, into a native executable. For details, see http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jetoverview.html (Disclaimer: I work for Excelsior)