# What happened to JEP 145 (faster jvm startup due to compiled code reusage)?

Tags: performance, optimization, jit, java

In 2012, [a JEP 145](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jep/jeps/rev/a16daa94ba0f) has been created in order to
 **cache compiled native code** in java for **faster jvm startups**.

At that time, [it had been officially announced.](https://twitter.com/openjdk/status/174648974618263552)
However, the [JEP 145 does not exist](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/145) anymore.

**What happened to it?** The idea sounds great.
I could not find an official statement why and when this project has been cancelled.

Comment: You should ask the OpenJDK community that. It's a bit off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The idea sounds great, but the attempt to implement it might have proven otherwise. After all, the potential gain is a fraction of the non-I/O part of your application’s startup time. Try to measure that, then consider that you have to *add* I/O time for loading the cached code. I wouldn’t be surprised if it turned out to be not worth the effort. There might be the other detail, that compiled code, created for code paths the application took *after* the startup, don’t help, if the application doesn’t take them *during* the startup.

Comment: @Holger Some (possibly wrong) counterarguments: The cached code can be loaded in one piece without any seeks. It might be possible to start it executing it before the bytecode gets loaded. The compiled code created for a different code paths is most probably still much faster than the interpreted one. It should be possible to create code optimized for the startup. +++ But you may be right. However, I guess it could work, but the limited gain and the typical Java usage make it not worth the effort.

Comment: @maaartinus: the possibility to load code in one piece is a matter of the file format and jar files are indeed horrible, but that has been addressed with the “shared class data” archive for JRE code already (which does indeed accelerate the startup) and will likely be addressed with Java 9 modules for arbitrary libraries. If a (compiled) code path is not taken, it doesn’t help that it would be faster than the (interpreted) code path actually taken. Creating optimized startup code would solve this, but is a totally different feature than just dumping the JIT results for future use.

Answer (score 2):

The text of the JEP is still available in the [JEP source repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jep/jeps/file/c915dfb4117d):

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jep/jeps/raw-file/c915dfb4117d/jep-145.md

There doesn't seem to be a documented reason for it to be canceled. But we now know that [AOT is in the works](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) and it solves many of the same problems, possibly in a way that's easier to implement and maintain. In fact, the AOT JEP says:

> It is possible that saving a very late copy of the low-level IR could be done instead, but that seems no less complex.

That certainly seems like an explanation of why 145 is not the way to go.