# Saving JVM optimisations and loading them at start up

Tags: java, jvm

I'm sure I read somewhere that it's possible to save the optimizations made by the JVM (after warmup) and reload at start up and therefore not have to warm up the jvm. Is this possible? The word that springs to mind is "checkpoints" but a search for "JVM checkpoints" yields nothing useful.

Comment: You probably mean [Java Checkpoint/Restore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xLAPgAjMR4). But that's not something that is ready for production use.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779339/java-jvm-hotspot-is-there-a-way-to-save-jit-performance-gains-at-compile-time

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62310971/3448419) covers up-to-date state of reusing Java compiled code.